# What is the fastest way to copy a colour in Photoshop as HEX?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color, ios, hex

A lot of designers use Photoshop as a design and mockup tool. And in doing so, one of the last steps can be to get a lot of the colour information out so things like gradients and dynamic text can be rebuilt using HTML, CSS, Cocoa or some other language.

Sampling a colour, then opening the picker and tabbing or double clicking the HEX field, then pressing ⌘C (Mac) or Control-C (Windows) requires a few steps.

If you have a final design document and you'd like to copy lots of colours to the clipboard, what's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: My somewhat related Q on StackOverflow: [Are there any good reasons for using hex over decimal for RGB colour values in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171422/are-there-any-good-reasons-for-using-hex-over-decimal-for-rgb-colour-values-in-c)

Comment: Good question. For me, it's far easier to transport the colours around as HEX, because only a single copy/paste is needed. Often the colours end up as NSColor or UIColor anyway. HEX is just the quickest way to get it out of Photoshop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Color panel has some well hidden abilities to copy the foreground colour to the clipboard. These can be assigned to a keyboard shortcut. I use ⌥⌘C.

[image: Copy colour keyboard shortcut]

It's also possible to right click with the eyedropper tool. This is quicker if you're sampling many colours.

[image: Eyedropper tool copy colour]

Answer (score -1):

You may use an awesome software called Colorpic (www.iconico.com/colorpic/) - it will enable you to create palettes for different projects that can be referred to at a later stage.