# Eyedropper straight to clipboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I think this is a pretty simple request, but how can i get it so that when i select a colour on my image using the eyedropper that is goes to my clipboard without me having to open up the dialogue box and coping it.

I'll be using this in photoshop and fireworks.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think it's possible. Excellent feature request though.

Comment: These _are_ the droids you're looking for: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8481/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-a-colour-in-photoshop-as-hex

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to sample a colour in one programme (PhotoShop) and have this go direct to the keyboard, say as a hex representation. Then you will be able to paste this directly into Fireworks, or indeed any programme that requires a colour as text. For this you require an external utility. The best I have found is Jay Prall's [Color Cop](http://colorcop.net), which is freeware for Windows OS. It does exactly this, with a good number of handy customisations features.